# Calculating $\int_{-1}^{1} e^{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t+\frac{\pi}{2})}dx$ by using gauss method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Today I had an exam ,
I’m reviewing my answers so I calculated one of the questions with maple after my exam and the answer is not anything near my answer
And also i don’t know what I’m doing wrong,i cannot find the flaw in my handcalculated answer

The question is :
Find the approximate integral using gauss method on two points
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{\sin x} dx$$

**What I did on paper** :

$x=\frac{\pi}{2}t+\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\int_{-1}^{1} e^{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t+\frac{\pi}{2})}dt = f(\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{3})+ f(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}) $

$e^{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{3} +\frac{\pi}{2})} + e^{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} +\frac{\pi}{2})} $

Then by expanding $\sin(a+b)$ we get

$\int_{-1}^{1} e^{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t+\frac{\pi}{2})}dx = 2.e^{\cos(\frac{-\sqrt 3}{6}\pi)}=3.70....  $

And by calculating it with maple it have to be somwhere around 6.2 which is absolutely not

Any help?

Comment: Write \sin for sin

Comment: @SaikaiPrime um no ?

Comment: @Negar Ok, I'll do it for you then.

Comment: @K.defaoite ok thankyou

Answer (score 1):

The result you got $2 e^{\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)}\approx 3.7$
is fine since the *Mathematica* exact result is $3.95262$.

Furthermore in the image below it can be seen that the rectangle approximates pretty well the desired integral.

[image]

Comment: Makes sense to me , but can you please take the time to look at the other answer and tell me what he did ?

Comment: @Negar You introduced $\int_0^{\pi} e^{\sin x}\,dx$ and the other contributor thought that you substituted $\pi/2 t $ with $x$. Better delete the integral in $x$ from your question. Your work is OK. I just didn't get the *Maple* reference. The exact value is $3.95262...$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you changed the variable in the function to integrate, but still have $dx$. That's not right. You need to replace $$dx=\frac{\pi}2 dt$$Then the answer will be approximately $\frac\pi 23.70=5.81$

Comment: Why shouldn’t I replace dx with dt ? Where did that $frac{\pi}{2}$ come from ? And also can you check the other guy’s answer ?

Comment: Numerically, the original integral is about $6.2$. The issue that you have is that you did not do a proper change of variable. $$\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{\sin x} dx=\frac\pi2\int_{-1}^{1} e^{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t+\frac{\pi}{2})}dt$$
Just see what is $dx/dt$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution